# How to retrieve exactly match values of available `startTime` key from given array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `slots` collection.
Whose response is given below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e32e55c9c058304f71eab70"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 1,
    "startTime" : 600,
    "isBooked" : false,
    "isClosed" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e32e55c9c058304f71eab71"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 1,
    "startTime" : 615,
    "isBooked" : false,
    "isClosed" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e32e55c9c058304f71eab72"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 1,
    "startTime" : 630,
    "isBooked" : true,
    "isClosed" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e32e55c9c058304f71eab73"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 1,
    "startTime" : 645,
    "isBooked" : false,
    "isClosed" : false
}
```

I have an array of `startTime` like:

```
[ 615, 630 ]
```

And I want to get all selected value not any one. I want to get all `slots` for `615`, `630`.
If any one `slot` is not available than I don't need those results.

Here are my queries: (with `$all`)

```
db.slots.find({ isBooked: false, isClosed: false, date: { $gte: new Date("Mon, 27 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT"), $lte: new Date("Mon, 27 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT") }, startTime: { $all: [ 615, 630 ] } })
```

It gives nothing. I know why? (It's only for testing)

With `$in`:

```
db.slots.find({ isBooked: false, isClosed: false, date: { $gte: new Date("Mon, 27 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT"), $lte: new Date("Mon, 27 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT") }, startTime: { $in: [ 615, 630 ] } })
```

It gives one record.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e32e55c9c058304f71eab71"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "dayOfWeek" : 1,
    "startTime" : 615,
    "isBooked" : false,
    "isClosed" : false
}
```

If `615` and `630` records available than I get both `records` otherwise I don't need this one `record`. I want complete set of `[ 615, 630 ]` records.

Comment: @turivishal I don't want to remove `isBooked: false` condition. Please check my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is possible with just `find()`, but it is possible with `aggregate()`, there are many ways in aggregation but i am suggesting one of them,

- get records in `c1` for your first condition `[ 615, 630 ]`
- get records in `c2` for your first and second other conditions

```
db.getCollection('datetime').aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            // will create a array of your first matching condition
            c1: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        startTime: { $in: [ 615, 630 ] } 
                    }
                }
            ],
            // will create a array of your second matching condition
            c2: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        startTime: { $in: [ 615, 630 ] },
                        isBooked: false, 
                        isClosed: false,
                        date: { 
                            $gte: new Date("Mon, 27 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT"), 
                            $lte: new Date("Mon, 27 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT") 
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

- condition will check both `c1` and `c2` are same then return one of them otherwise blank array in `result` key.

```
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $cond: [
                   // check condition if both are same then then return one of them otherwise empty 
                   { $setEquals: ["$c1", "$c2"]},
                   "$c1",
                   []
               ]
           }
        }
    },
```

- unwind `result` because we need to replace result in root
- replace result in root

```
    // unwind main result because it is array
    { $unwind: "$result" },
    // replace your unwind result in root it will make multiple object
    { 
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$result"
        } 
    }
])
```

For the explanation purpose i have divided in to parts, you can merge easily as all are in sequence.

Working playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dxZN9TMlR61